# Any Angular app is not running in any of the browsers

Tags: angular, npm, localhost

[image]My any of the Angular application is not running in browser when I try to run by `ng serve` command. Everytime I got the following Message into browser:

> This site can’t be reached.
>
> localhost took too long to respond.

I tried reinstalling `npm`, updating `package.json` but actually problem is something different as any angular 2 or angular 4 app is not responding.

Any help appreciated. I will upload package.json if anyone want to verify.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console where you ran the `ng-serve`?

Comment: No. Console is empty

Comment: it's **empty**??  does it even say that it started the server?

Comment: No, Its empty. strange for me too. I updated the question with screenshot as well

Comment: please note, I asked about the console where you ran `ng-serve` (command prompt or simillar), **not** the browser console.

Comment: oh!! cmd prompt says:
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Comment: it sounds like there is something environmental on your machine.  do you have a virus scanner or firewall that might be blocking port 4200?

Comment: I'd love to help, but trying to figure out a firewall issue isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: Yes I have a Avast virus scanner recently installed on my machine. But Although I disable the Firewall feature OR even change the port number by ng serve --port 5369 -o still getting no response

Comment: In my case, it was a server crash issue as server was unable to handle 2 applications installed & running. Also, both the applications was always running with all resources, consuming entire server and made it to crash every time. 

I'm not sure about your case but one should check this as well. 

Note: We spent almost an entire week to figure out this issue as we were only checking our app, not server.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is resolved by removing and adding Node.js from my firewall settings.